# Unexport all variables for a particular Makefile recipe

Tags: makefile, export

I was wondering if it was possible to call make from within a makefile recipe, but have it so the new invokation does not inherit the current makefile's exported variables.

For example:

```
include $(TRG).vars
OLD_TRG=`cat .last_trg`

all:
    if [ $(TRG) -ne $(OLD_TRG) ]; then \
        read -p "Clean required -- press enter"; \
        make clean TRG=$(OLD_TRG); \
    fi
    echo $(TRG) > .last_trg

clean:
    [ $(SOMEVAR) ] && rm -rf $(SOMEVAR)
```

If, for the above, `SOMEVAR` was defined in `$(TRG).vars`, but not in `$(OLD_TRG).vars`, then the `make clean` invocation would inherit `SOMEVAR` from the parent makefile, and might clean the wrong directory.   I would want the make clean to not inherit any of the environment from the current makefile so it could clean independently.

Comment: Use `env -i make` in the target?

Comment: my understanding is that env -i clears the shell environment -- not the makefile environment.   There may be some varialbes in the shell environment (eg. PATH), which would be required in the child makefile.  I want to unexport things which are specifically set within the makefile...

Comment: Things set in the makefile are passed to sub-make invocations (and all other shell/etc. invocations through the environment. That's the only channel available. See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion and http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion for more on this.

Comment: Ahh, I had read that, but I glossed over the sentence where it explained that.   I'll try to backup the environment when make is first invoked, and then restore it when I call the submake...   Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear: make doesn't put all make variables into the sub-make's environment.  Only variables which were in the environment that make inherited from its parent, plus any variables explicitly specified as `export` in the makefile, will be exported to the sub-make via the environment.

Comment: Also, you generally never want to invoke `make` directly when starting a sub-make.  You should use `$(MAKE)` instead.